# angular state: abstract: true, how can I tell a child to not use parent template

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes, state

Is it possible to tell a specific child to not use the parent html template using abstract set to true ?

```
$stateProvider
.state('contacts', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/:my_id/contacts',
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
})
.state('contacts.list', {
    url: 'list',
    // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
    templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
})
.state('contacts.detail', {
    url: 'detail',
    'dontUseParentTemplate': true, // something like that
    // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
    templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html'
})
```

Comment: do you want multiple base template?

Comment: I don't want to include the /:my_id to the url of my childs

Comment: please see this. may be help you https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views